# Perform an update via left join in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Normally, I would be making this table with one SELECT statement with correlated subqueries, but I can't in Snowflake?  Anyway, I want to update all rows in a table, with a special value (9999) for the ones that don't match.
In T-SQL, I would do something like

```
update x
set x.value = coalesce(n.value2, 9999)
from x
left join n
on x.id = n.id
```

How can I do the same in Snowflake?

Comment: I still want to know this but I looked at another thread that says that more robust correlated subquery support exists now...

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/update.html) you don't use the `JOIN` keyword but instead do the join in the `WHERE` like this:

```
update t1
  set t1.number_column = t1.number_column + t2.number_column, t1.text_column = 'ASDF'
from t2
where t1.key_column = t2.t1_key and t1.number_column < 10;
```

Comment: Also, in Snowflake UPDATE X .. FROM X means you're actually using the rows of the 2nd X to update the rows of the 1st X. It's a common mistake when people transition from SqlServer. You just don't need the updated table in the FROM clause.

Comment: but isn't the join by default an INNER JOIN? and what in case if we have to perform any other joins?

Comment: @Kulasangar I don't see the point in doing a left join + update. If there is no matching record in the right table, what would you put in the column on the left side of the join?

Comment: @SimonD so basically i only need the join to get one column to use it in under the where clause and i'm not using it to update the columns of the base table (the table i'm updating); hence the reason for my question? So in that case if I use the inner join, it will only update the records of that are matching from the join where as i want to update all of them

Answer (score 3):

To achieve left join in where clause in Snowflake, the (+) operator can be used.

```
update table1 x
set x.value = coalesce(n.value2, 9999)
from table2 n
where ( x.id = n.id(+))
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/where.html)

`

> Outer joins can be specified in the WHERE clause using the (+) syntax.
> To specify an outer join using (+), the columns from the
> NULL-augmented table of the join are annotated with the (+) in the
> WHERE clause.

`

Comment: This approach is only recommended for porting existing code, not new development, according to the same docs. However it does seem to be the only way to reproduce the functionality of an update from a left join in SQL Server.

Comment: Right, that was our use case- As-is migration.!

Answer (score 1):

@Simon Darr Left joins are often needed in updates to ensure that non-matching records are set to NULL. For example, if you have a set of records with existing values and you want to do an update to overwrite those values, based on joined subtables, you'll want to ensure that any records for which there are no joined subrecords get set to NULL.

By using an INNER JOIN (or the WHERE in Snowflake) it means that recors with no matching subrecords will be excluded from the update, thus leaving values on those records unchanged. This would leave old, out of date, and potentially invalid data in place. You can get around this by using to steps, first nulling out all of the values and then doing the update, but this seems highly inefficient and error prone compared to what can be done in SQL Server with a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the task into two separate queries, handling when the tables match, and when they don't.

When they don't match, you can use WHERE NOT EXISTS syntax:

```
update x
set x.value = 9999
from x
where not exists (select 1
                  from n
                  where x.id = n.id)
```

And when they do match:

```
update x
set x.value = n.value2
from n
where x.id = n.id
```

Answer (score -2):

we can use merge to get away with this

```
merge tablea a 
using (
select b.colpkb,b.colx , c.coly,c.colpkc
from tablea b 
left join tableb c on b.colpkb=c.colpkc
) lf
on a.colpka= lf.colpkb
when matched 
then update 
set 
a.colx=lf.colx;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address the original question, which is how to update a table based on a "left join" i.e. update rows where there is _no match_ as well as ones that match.