Snowflake update using left join
Created 4 tables in both SQL Server and Snowflake.
Inserted these values.
INSERT INTO t1 (id, name, v) VALUES
(1, 'Name1_T1', 100),
(2, 'Name2_T1', 200),
(3, 'Name3_T1', 300),
(4, 'Name4_T1', 300),
(5, 'Name5_T1', 300);

INSERT INTO t2 (id, name, v) VALUES
(4, 'Name1_T2', 400),
(1, 'Name3_T2', 600); 


INSERT INTO t3 (id, name, v) VALUES
(4, 'Name3_T3', 900);


INSERT INTO t4 (id, name, v) VALUES
(2, 'Name3_T4', 1200); 

This is my SQL Server syntax:
update t1
set v = 0
from t1 table1
left outer join t2 table2
on table1.id = table2.id
left outer join t3 table3
on table2.id = table3.id
left outer join t4 table4
on table3.id = table4.id
where table1.id = 2;

This is in Snowflake
update t1
set v = 0
from t1 table1
left outer join t2 table2
on table1.id = table2.id
left outer join t3 table3
on table2.id = table3.id
left outer join t4 table4
on table3.id = table4.id
where table1.id = 2;

But SQL Server returns 1 row, snowflake returns 5. Is there any other way to get 1 row in snowflake.
SQL Server changes column v for id 2 to 0 in t1, But Snowflake makes all column v as 0 in all 5 ids in t1.

returns 1 row ... do you mean the DB says 1 row affected?  In any case, the two queries appear identical, you should check your data.

Rather than comparing to SQL Server, provide a [MRE] with sample data and desired results and your query.

@TimBiegeleisen data is same in both. But snowflake updates all 5 rows in t1, but mssql updates only 1 row.

@DaleK made changes.

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605449/perform-an-update-via-left-join-in-snowflake and other related questions?

@DaleK I checked it, but I am not able to write exact syntax for multiple left joins.

I tried the select with Left outer join and it returns only one rows, but the update with left outer join updates 5 rows.
create  or replace table t1 (id varchar(10), name varchar(100), v number) ;
create  or replace table t2 (id varchar(10), name varchar(100), v number) ;
create  or replace   table t3 (id varchar(10), name varchar(100), v number) ;
create  or replace   table t4 (id varchar(10), name varchar(100), v number) ;

INSERT INTO t1 (id, name, v) VALUES
(1, 'Name1_T1', 100),
(2, 'Name2_T1', 200),
(3, 'Name3_T1', 300),
(4, 'Name4_T1', 300),
(5, 'Name5_T1', 300);

INSERT INTO t2 (id, name, v) VALUES
(4, 'Name1_T2', 400),
(1, 'Name3_T2', 600); 


INSERT INTO t3 (id, name, v) VALUES
(4, 'Name3_T3', 900);


INSERT INTO t4 (id, name, v) VALUES
(2, 'Name3_T4', 1200); 
    -- returns 1 row
    select table1.id,table1.* from 
      t1 table1
    left outer join t2 table2
    on table1.id = table2.id
    left outer join t3 table3
    on table2.id = table3.id
    left outer join t4 table4
    on table3.id = table4.id
    where table1.id = 2;
    

--You can try with the (+) syntax for left outer join and it updates one row. 
   
     update t1 table1
    set v = 0
    from  t2 table2 , t3 table3
    ,t4 table4
    where table1.id = 2  and
    table1.id = table2.id(+) and
     table2.id = table3.id(+) and 
      table3.id = table4.id(+)
    ;


